# Struct with Vector of Structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Sorry, the title sounds a little confusing, let me explain.

I have a struct, which has a vector of structs, like this:

```
struct foo {
int x;
vector < foo > bar;
};
```

But I get an error of "No Instance of Overloaded Method" when I try this syntax:

```
foo a;
foo b;
b.x = 3;
a.bar.push_back(b);
```

Basically, I am just trying to create a "relationship" between `a` and `b`, with `bar` being the relationship vector containing all related instances of `foo`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Same here, Code compile just fine with g++. Are you getting a run time error?

Comment: There is nothing with your code _if it is C++_. ***[vector](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html)*** is not defined for C

Comment: @ryyker neither is overloading

Comment: Is this std::vector? Or some other implementation

Comment: @BugKiller - not sure what that has to do with my comment, (except that you are a person with a sense of humor)  I am referring to the tag "C", and since OP has not answer what the compiler is, ...

Comment: I don't see a syntax problem.  I do wonder, though, if you actually want `vector< foo& >` as opposed to `vector< foo >`.

Comment: @JoeZ: you cannot have `vector< foo& >`.

Comment: Hmm perhaps I just jumped to conclusions. Visual Studio was showing the error, but it seems to compile file. Thank you all!

Comment: @n.m.:  You are right, a thinko on my part.  The main point, though, is that copying all of `b` into `a.bar` is probably not what the original poster ultimately wants.  You probably want pointers or some other indirection here, not a copy.

Comment: @rykker I meant that if OP were using a C compiler they would not get a C++ related error message

Comment: @BugKiller - I see that now, thanks.  I stopped reading when I saw `vector <...>`, coupled with the "C" tag.  My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is, unfortunately, illegal according to the C++ Standard, because you are passing an incomplete type as a template parameter to the Standard Library, which is prohibited in general and `std::vector` doesn't have an exception to the general rule.

The Boost documentation [has a great explanation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html).

You can either use a container which explicitly supports incomplete types, as the Boost ones do, or use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>>`, because the Standard says in 20.9.1p5:

> The template parameter `T` of `unique_ptr` may be an incomplete type.

Answer (score -1):

May be it's your compiler, Mine gives no error or warnings.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



struct foo {
int x;
vector < foo > bar;
};


int main()
{
foo a;
foo b;
b.x = 3;
a.bar.push_back(b);
cout<<a.bar[0].x;
    cout<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong except for violating rule 17.6.4.8 and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, I didn't get any exception or warning whatsoever, so I guess we can live with this violation, can't we?

Comment: That's a very dangerous approach to undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, that was me being casual? Here's my question, if there is a violation in documentation then shouldn't that reflect in compiler?

Comment: Obviously it is better when the compiler can detect undefined behavior and warn you about it, but the Standard doesn't require a diagnostic for this case -- and there are some well-known cases of undefined behavior which cannot be detected at compile time.

Comment: Whoever down voted my answer kindly explain what's wrong in it. It's not MY fault that compiler is compiling correctly and there is no run time error.

Comment: Your edit "removing the claim that the code in the question is correct" made your answer correct.  It also made it more of a comment than a complete answer, but because of the SSCCE and the image, it's not possible to make it a comment.  And that it works with your version of G++ is relevant information.  I therefore disagree with whoever downvoted.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks. Down-vote clearly says "THE ANSWER IS NOT USEFUL". I don't see my answer as not useful or misleading in any sense and as you very clearly said this kind of response is also not possible as a comment. Most of the time these down-voters are members with very high reps, a low rep member would think twice before doing so. Such a shame.